# python call to popen.communicate gives no output

Tags: python

I have a class function declared as

```
    def catFunc(self,filename):
    print "catFunc",filename
    process = subprocess.Popen(['cat',/root/scratch.php], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    out, err = process.communicate()
    print (out)
    print (err)
```

and called like this

```
fn = '/root/scratch.php'
self.catFunc(fn)
```

But I see no output and cannot figure out why

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe the process hasn't [terminated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)? Or better yet check whether the Popen has failed, by printing its `process.returncode`.

Comment: The return code is None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read content of file

```
def catFunc(self,filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        s = f.read()
    return s
```

If you need to use the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess

def catFunc(filename):
    print "catFunc"
    task = subprocess.Popen(["cat", filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print list(task.stdout)

catFunc()
```

Comment: I know I can dot that - my purpose is to undestand the popen.communicate function

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the output of a shell command it's recommend to use `subprocess.check_output` in cooperation with `shlex.split`.

For instance:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split('cat "root/scratch.php"')
```

That said, Rakesh is correct based on the current question title.